Before Trigger - Validate data prior to assigning?
I'm wondering if there's any benefit to adding an if statement to check if data changed prior to modifying in a before trigger (assuming I'd always want that specific value). The example below is quite simple and could be done in a formula, but my question is really for when a formula field cannot suffice.
For example:
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert){

  for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
    String preferredTitle = getTitleFromLead(ld)){
    if(ld.Title != preferredTitle){
        ld.Title = preferredTitle;
    }
   }
 }

 public static String getTitleFromLead(Lead ld){
   String title;
   //some complicated logic here, will never return null
   return title;
 }    
}

OR:
 trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert){

  for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
      ld.Title = getTitleFromLead(ld);
  }

 public static String getTitleFromLead(Lead ld){
  String title;
  //some complicated logic here, will never return null
   return title;
 }    
}

Is there a point in first checking that the Title != preferredTitle before I assign - this is in before insert context. Is one considered better practice/more efficient/cleaner? I understand this is a very nitty-gritty question, and as developers we can't spend too much time on simplifying to such an intense degree. Regardless, I am still curious if there's a right/wrong answer here?

There can be really good reasons to determine whether to update a field - take a look at this article for some considerations (yes, for update rather than insert). Honestly, I think if the "complicated logic" is using various other fields on the record, you should only update the title when one of those fields actually changes (on update) and only set the field if it doesn't already have a value on insert. That way you don't lose user-originated data unless it really makes sense to do so.

What you're looking at here is what I would call a micro-optimization. At a max of 10k rows that can go through this trigger in any given transaction, an extra variable assignment and if() with a single string comparison; any difference in "performance" (cpu time, "real"/clock time, heap space used, etc...) just isn't going to be measurable.
I would say that the decision to go with one approach over another here boils down to:

Are you possibly going to re-use this logic in an update trigger? (keep the check if yes)
What does the rest of your codebase look like? Be consistent with that; consistency is king

In general, I'd prefer the approach that requires less typing. The idea being that less typing = fewer chances to make a mistake or introduce a bug.
If you're only using this in a before insert context, then just doing the assignment minimizes typing.
Likewise, if you're using it in both insert and update contexts, keeping the check minimizes typing (because you can use the same logic for both contexts instead of making "special" logic for one or the other).
Of course, you should also be looking at using a trigger framework so you are keeping the logic outside of the trigger (which makes the logic easier to re-use and easier to test in isolation, among other things).

My opinion...
This entirely depends on the business requirements. However, there are some general considerations around losing data created outside the system. In the examples you showed in your question, in both cases you could be discarding a value that has been explicitly set. Of course, that may be what the business wants, but (IMO) generally speaking that is a bad idea if it doesn't make the data invalid; someone spent time determining a value to set and may have a good reason to do this that your code isn't aware of.
If you are only doing this on insert, I wouldn't test the value but instead I would only look to generate and assign a computed value if the field (Title) has no value. That way if an integration or user has created the record with a title already, that value is retained.
If you extend this to update then:

Check to see if the DML is already updating the Title and, if so, leave it alone (again, depending on business requirement).
If there's no update to Title but there are changes to one of the inputs that are used when calculating the new value for the title, compute the new value and store it.

In none of these scenarios would I do the test to see if the existing title does or does not match the new computed value; it's not the computed value that is important but rather how that value is computed.
If, for example, the getTitleFromLead "complicated logic" uses other fields from the record, it makes sense to check to see if one or more of these have changed in order to decide whether to update the Title with the new value.
In the end there's no right or wrong answer here; it's all about what the business wants.

Phil brings up a good point that overwriting a (presumably) user set title with the "preferred title" seems wrong. If you're always going to overwrite it, don't let them set it and thus no need for the check. Or check whether they do set it and only set if unset.

You have a method called getTitleFromLead and it is passed the Lead record. Based on that method's name, it should take responsibility for deciding/using the existing Lead.Title, if any.
Hence, your trigger should just be
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert){

  for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
    ld.Title = getTitleFromLead(ld)){
    
  }
}

Or, even better; change the method name to getTitle as the argument is a Lead so it is explicit that the title comes from the Lead.  Less-is-more.
